# How to convert EventRecord xml to dictionary includes all parameters - C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following xml which include windows event:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?> -
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="LMS" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="32768">2125</EventID>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>3</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2021-05-30T14:05:07.077547800Z" />
    <EventRecordID>89958</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer></Computer>
    <Security/>
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data> </Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

I wand to convert this XML to dictionary in c#, it's work fine but the problem is that in the "provider Name" and "timeCreated" properties I'm receiving null.

Any idea how can I get the values like: "LMS" and "2021-05-30T14:05:07.077547800Z" ?

Here is the code to converting the XML to dictionary:

```js
var xmlFile = File.ReadAllText(log);
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlFile);
Dictionary<string, string > dataDictionary = new Dictionary <string, string >();
foreach(XElement element in doc.Descendants().Where(p => p.HasElements ==false)) 
{
  int keyInt = 0;
  string keyName = element.Name.LocalName;
  while (dataDictionary.ContainsKey(keyName))
  {
    keyName = element.Name.LocalName + "_" + keyInt++;
  }
  dataDictionary.Add(keyName,
    element.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following checks if the XML node has any attributes and if so will get the value of the attribute and add the value of the dictionary with the key in the format `nodeName_attributeName`:

```
var xmlFile = File.ReadAllText(log);
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlFile);
Dictionary<string, string > dataDictionary = new Dictionary <string, string >();
foreach(XElement element in doc.Descendants().Where(p => p.HasElements ==false)) 
{
    int keyInt = 0;
    string keyName = element.Name.LocalName;
    while (dataDictionary.ContainsKey(keyName))
    {
        keyName = element.Name.LocalName + "_" + keyInt++;
    }
    dataDictionary.Add(keyName, element.Value);

    if (element.HasAttributes)
    {
        var lmsAttribute = element.FirstAttribute;
        if (lmsAttribute != null)
        {
            dataDictionary.Add($"{keyName}_{lmsAttribute.Name.LocalName}", lmsAttribute.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Final dictionary looks like this:

```
{
  "Provider": "",
  "Provider_Name": "LMS",
  "EventID": "2125",
  "EventID_Qualifiers": "32768",
  "Level": "4",
  "Task": "3",
  "Keywords": "0x80000000000000",
  "TimeCreated": "",
  "TimeCreated_SystemTime": "2021-05-30T14:05:07.077547800Z",
  "EventRecordID": "89958",
  "Channel": "Application",
  "Computer": "",
  "Security": "",
  "Data": ""
}
```

[See this DotNetFiddle for a demonstration](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Vf8uU2)